# Error: Spark-Submit DAG cannot locate GCS Connector file in Airflow container

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage, airflow, spark-submit

I'd like your help with an error I am getting whilst trying to run a spark-submit job within an Airflow container.
I've built two images - one for Airflow and one for Spark and run docker-compose files for each application. I then run `docker-compose` up and configure the Spark connection within the Airflow UI by defining the host with the master-node URI in the connection settings and ensure the conn-id there matches that used in the DAG.
Reading the LOG, it appears as if the DAG seems to not be able to locate the JAR file responsible to connect to GCS (gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.5.jar). I cannot pinpoint whether this is a path issue (relative/absolute), a permissions issue or something completely different.

The following is the Spark Job

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    conf = SparkConf() \
        .setMaster('local') \
        .setAppName('test') \
        .set("spark.jars", "/spark-lib/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.5.jar") \ 
        .set("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true") \
        .set("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", './.google/credentials/google_credentials.json')

    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf.set("spark.files.overwrite", "true"))

    hadoop_conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

    hadoop_conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl",  "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", './.google/credentials/google_credentials.json')
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")


    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .config(conf=sc.getConf()) \
        .getOrCreate()

    path = "gs://tfl-cycling/pq/" 
    df_test = spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").parquet(path)
    df_test.printSchema()
```

The DAG:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator 
import pendulum

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkFiles
from pyspark.sql import types
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

import pandas as pd
import datetime


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',    
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}


spark_dag = DAG(
        dag_id = "test_1",
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule=None,  
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
        description='use case of sparkoperator in airflow',
        start_date = pendulum.today('UTC').add(days=-1)
)


Etl = SparkSubmitOperator(
        application = "/opt/airflow/dags/example.py", 
        conn_id= 'spark_default',#'spark_local', 
        task_id='spark_submit_task_load', 
        dag=spark_dag
        )

Etl
```

The error message:

```
2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add ./../gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.5.jar to Spark environment
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar /opt/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.5.jar not found
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addLocalJarFile$1(SparkContext.scala:1968)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addJar(SparkContext.scala:2023)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$12(SparkContext.scala:507)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$12$adapted(SparkContext.scala:507)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:507)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host 8923728d9f5c
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO Executor: Starting executor with user classpath (userClassPathFirst = false): ''
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 35925.
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 8923728d9f5c:35925
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 8923728d9f5c, 35925, None)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 8923728d9f5c:35925 with 434.4 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 8923728d9f5c, 35925, None)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 8923728d9f5c, 35925, None)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 8923728d9f5c, 35925, None)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py:317: FutureWarning: Python 3.7 support is deprecated in Spark 3.4.
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - warnings.warn("Python 3.7 support is deprecated in Spark 3.4.", FutureWarning)
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
[2023-04-18, 08:50:05 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:05 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/opt/***/spark-warehouse'.
[2023-04-18, 08:50:06 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/04/18 08:50:06 WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path: gs://tfl-cycling/pq/.
[2023-04-18, 08:50:06 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
```

I've tried to define the `spark.jars` value as both absolute and relative paths
I've tried to provide additional permission to read the file.
I've also tried to use `"spark.jars.packages", "com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-2.2.5"` instead of a 'local' file but here I think my implementation might require additonal research on how to correctly set the configuration with the script.

Lastly, I've tried submitting the job to the Spark container directly and was successful to run the job you see above (which is more of an example).

My expectation with this job is to be able to read parquet files that are stored on GCS and run some analysis and transformations with Spark but firstly just be able to connect to GCS and read the files there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - whilst I copied the JAR file into the image, I did not mount the volume within the relevant service properly (in this case airflow-scheduler). Once I added the mount to the service within the docker-compose file, the file was recognized.
Side note, previously whilst debugging the issue, I copied the file manually to the container with the `docker cp`, however, it seems that while the command worked airflow could still not access the file - therefore he too one would need to set a mount of the file/directory manually as well.